# Adding a new subfield to a field of all documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5d6eb64a2a33670cfe44813f"},
    "customer":"ddd",
    "owners": { "a":"nnn", "b":"mmm"},
}
```

I have multiple documents in my MongoDB collection that look like above.
I want to be able to add a new field inside the `owners` to all documents.
For example, if I want to add `"c"` to the `owners` of all documents, how can I do that?

I found a query that does something like this:

```
db.myCollection.update({}, {$set: {"isOpen": false}}, false, true)
```

But I can I add a new sub-field (`"c"`) to one of the fields (`"owners"`) of my document?

Also tried,

```
db.profiles.update_many({}, { '$set': {'owners': {'c': ''}}})
```

but this removes the existing subfields and adds itself.

Comment: Take a look at this answer here. It aims to do something similar - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069554/5512274

Comment: It's slightly different. That one changes the structure, but I am just trying to add a new subfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just need to add the parent to the $set:

```
db.profiles.update_many({},{$set: {"owners.c": "something"}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should remove $set, set overwrites an existing document